# Google Cloud Monitoring groups are including instances that are already closed for a brief time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have configured a group on Google Cloud Monitoring to select gce_instances following a naming convention for a predefined instance group. However, I have noticed that it seems to include instances that have already been deleted for a brief time (ie. right after a replacement of the vms in the instance group). This is causing additional alerts to be sent for an uptime check that was created for the monitoring group because the uptime checks are still being performed for vms that are already deleted. Is there a way to configure criteria for the group to only consider vm instances that are actually running?

I have also set up autohealing for the instance group with the same triggering conditions as the uptime check which is being used in conjunction with the uptime check. Would it be possible to configure alerts on autohealing instead of using both in conjunction because of the aforementioned situation with uptime checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you wanted to configure criteria for the [monitoring group](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/groups) to only consider vm instances that are actually running, which is not available currently.

I have created a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/168052311). Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue and also track for future updates.